# Android LinearLayout static height converting to wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to inflate and display a LinearLayout with a specific height but when displayed the height always gets converted to wrap_content. My layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_title_height"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_padding">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Scan for devices" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarScanning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It seams fine at first but when I set the `ProgressBar` visibility to `View.GONE` then the layout height shrinks to the size of the TextView which is much smaller than the set `layout_height` on the parent layout.

But, if I wrap the views in a 2nd LinearLayout with the specified height and set the parent to `wrap_content` then it works just fine. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_padding">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_title_height">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Scan for devices" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarScanning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But now of course AndroidStudio complains that the 2nd `LinearLayout` is useless.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: you could use View.INVISIBLE for the progress bar.

Comment: I would rather have full control over the height without any magic such as that

Comment: it is not magic. It's full control. You don't want to be drawn but you want the view to take the space. INVISIBLE is meant for this purpose

Comment: But then it is relying on the `ProgressBar` to set the height but the layout itself should have the height, regardless of the children

Comment: the height of the LinearLayout (horizontal) is   the max height of its children

Comment: Ah, I get it then. But why bother setting a width/height to the parent layout then?

Comment: ja sorry, what I said before it's true for wrap_content. If the height of the Layout is match_parent it will take all the available space, independently of the children's height

Answer (score 0):

You can set weight for particular object and not to linear layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_padding">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_title_height"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Scan for devices" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarScanning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_title_height" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will works.

Comment: While this does work, it seams a bit hacky. Also, if I remove the weights from that TextView and just have height `match_parent` it still give the same problems

Comment: Use ProgressBar visibility to **View.INVISIBLE** instead of **View.GONE**.